# Ruby. Run a script in the background like in Node with Forever

Tags: ruby, node.js

Using Daemons right now, but I don't want to code the daemon, just want a script that restarts the server when it's killed and that storages logs.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd try [God](http://godrb.com/) gem.

Other information that may be useful for you:

1. [God en Github](https://github.com/railscasts/130-monitoring-with-god):
2. [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/130-monitoring-with-god)